# "style" field in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, package.json

I noticed that [Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/package.json#L19) and [Normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/package.json#L5) both have a "style" field in their package.json.

Why do they have this? If I had to guess, it's to allow users to import the defined stylesheet as easily as doing `require('bootstrap')`, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From Techwraith's [pull request](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/12441) that added it to Bootstrap:

> Many modules in npm are starting to expose their css entry files in
>   their package.json files. This allows tools like [`npm-css`](https://github.com/defunctzombie/npm-css),
>   [`rework-npm`](https://github.com/conradz/rework-npm), and [`npm-less`](https://github.com/Raynos/npm-less) to import bootstrap from the
>   node_modules directory. [...]
>
> It's actually not written anywhere but in the code for these modules
>   right now. We're hoping to get this standardized at some point, but
>   we've all reached this convention separately, so I'm inclined to just
>   go with it. [...]
>
> If you want to read about this style of css development, I wrote a
>   thing:
>
> http://techwraith.com/your-css-needs-a-dependency-graph-too/

There's also support in other tools, such as the browserify plugin [parcelify](https://github.com/rotundasoftware/parcelify):

> Add css to your npm modules consumed with browserify.
>
> - Just add a style key to your package.json to specify the package's css file(s). [...]
>
> Parcelify will concatenate all the css files in the modules on which
>   `main.js` depends -- in this case just `myModule.css` -- in the order
>   of the js dependency graph, and write the output to `bundle.css`.

Comment: Since most of the tools mentioned here aren't well maintained anymore, I though I would mention that https://github.com/postcss/postcss-import still uses the `style` property. (Disclosure: I am the maintainer of postcss-import.)