# Webpack / ES6: how to import stylesheets

Tags: npm, less, ecmascript-6, webpack, modularity

I see repositories like bootstrap starting to include additional tags in their [package.json file such as 'style' and 'less.'](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.0.0-alpha.2/package.json#L20-L22) How can I use these tags to import assets?

```
package.json

{
  "name": "bootstrap",
  "style": "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
  "sass": "scss/bootstrap.scss",
  "main": "./dist/js/npm"
}
```

I am using ES6 modules and webpack. I want to do be able to import my stylesheets using the style tag in package.json.

Currently I am doing something like this:

```
my_stylesheets.less

@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap";
```

which is annoying for consumers to add the path when it is available in package.json. Is there a way I can import stylesheets using the tag in package.json?

If I cannot use the tag in package.json, is there a standard way of importing stylesheets in ES6 modules?

Answer (score 0):

Yes!!! Webpack treats everything as a module, including that cute little `package.json` in your repo.

Therefore, you simply need to `require()` it into your app and then access properties from that json object. (See json-loader for more info).

I often use this to import data like version number etc for my Webpack config file for bundling and versioning.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not included in webpack for now. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/51) about this in webpack's CSS loader repo.

There is also an [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037150/style-field-in-package-json) on the use of the style field, and it seems that there are some npm / browserify tools that support this.