# Importing stylesheet in a server rendered react view - TypeError: style._getCss is not a function

Tags: reactjs, sass, redux, isomorphic-style-loader

I am building an isomorphic react-redux app on top of NodeJS. I am rendering my homePage from the server. However, my styles are not reflected in my rendered view. I would like to import stylesheets just how I do it on the client side. I tried [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36507147/webpack-es6-how-to-import-stylesheets) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30347722/importing-css-files-in-isomorphic-react-components) too, but neither of them actually got me what I want to achieve.

Here are more details on the project.

.babelrc

```
{
 "presets": [ "es2015", "react", "stage-0"],
 "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy", ["transform-assets", {
            "extensions": ["scss"],
            "name": "[name].[ext]?[sha512:hash:base64:7]",
          }]]
 }
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = [
    {
      name: 'client',
      target: 'web',
      entry: './routes/client.jsx',
      output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'assets'),
        filename: 'client.js',
        publicPath: '/assets/',
      },
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
      },
      devtool: 'source-map',
      module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules\/)/,
                use: [{ loader: 'babel-loader'}]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: 'isomorphic-style-loader' },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            modules: true,
                            importLoaders: 1,
                            localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    { loader: 'sass-loader'}
                ]
            }
        ],
    },
}];
```

server.js

```
import express from 'express'
import React from 'react'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import MainStore from './views/store/MainStore'
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Routes from './routes/routes';
import Template from './views/templates/template';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import ContextProvider from './routes/contextProvider'

const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware')
const config = require('./webpack/webpack.development.config.js')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const compiler = webpack(config);

let preloadedState = { shipper: {view: "from_server"} }

app.use('/assets', express.static('./assets'))
app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
   publicPath: "/assets/",
}));

app.use(handleRender);

function handleRender(req, res) {
   // Create a new Redux store instance
   const store = createStore(MainStore, preloadedState)
   const css = new Set(); // CSS for all rendered React components
   const context = { insertCss: (...styles) => styles.forEach(style =>   
   css.add(style._getCss())) }

   const html = renderToString(
     <Provider store={store}>
        <StaticRouter context={context}>
            <ContextProvider context={context}>
            <Routes />
        </ContextProvider>
        </StaticRouter>
     </Provider>
  )
  const finalState = store.getState()
  const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();
  const preloadedState = store.getState()
  res.send(renderFullPage(html, preloadedState));
 }

 function renderFullPage(html, finalState) {
    return `
      <!doctype html>
      <html>
         <head>
            <title>Redux Universal Example</title>
            <style type="text/css">${[...css].join('')}</style>
         </head>
         <body>
             <div id="root">${html}</div>
             <script>
                window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(preloadedState).replace(/</g, '\\u003c')}
             </script>
             <script src="./assets/client.js"></script>
         </body>
    </html>
    `
  }

app.listen(port)
```

contextProvider.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Routes from './routes.jsx';

export default class ContextProvider extends Component {
   static childContextTypes = {
   insertCss: PropTypes.func,
}

 getChildContext() {
    return { ...this.props.context }
  }

 render() {
    const { children, ...props } = this.props
    return React.cloneElement(children, props)
  }
}
```

I am importing it in my homePresenter as

```
import homePageStyle from './home.scss';
```

and using it in my div in the same component as

```
<div className="component">
```

If I change this to

```
<div className={homePageStyle.component}>
```

I get an error on the browser

```
TypeError: style._getCss is not a function at server.js:52:84
```

On the browser, I could see that the div has class name as 'component'; it;'s just it is not inheriting the styles.

Any suggestions on what I am missing here?

Comment: did you use `import withStyles from 'isomorphic-style-loader/lib/withStyles';` in your react component?

Comment: @Umesh Thank you for the lead. I inserted, but I am now running into a different issue. I followed the process here https://github.com/kriasoft/isomorphic-style-loader/issues/110 and https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/issues/378 and according to the documentation of isomorphic-style-loader, isomorphic-style-loader provides two helper methods on to the styles object - ._insertCss() (injects CSS into the DOM) and ._getCss() (returns a CSS string).  I am however getting the error "TypeError: style._getCss is not a function at server.js:52:84"

Answer (score -1):

> TypeError: style._getCss is not a function at server.js:52:84

Most likely that server-side rendering is not configured properly. If you are not using `webpack` for compiling server-side bundle, of course, appropriate styles will not loaded, since `isomorphic-style-loader` had not processed files on server-side.
Check how application is started and ensure, that `webpack` had been applied for server-bundle and configuration was like this: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/
Also you can try ready isomorphic solution with frontend+backend bundling and includes css support, like [resolve-app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-resolve-app).