# Adding font-awesome to project with webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I've bootstrap template and I'm trying to put this to [FountainJS](http://fountainjs.io/). I included all scss files from template and it's ok. Now i need to include eg font-awesome, so i used `npm install font-awesome --save` and add to `index.js` `require('font-awesome');` but it's still not available in project

My `src/index.js` file:

```
var angular = require('angular');

var techsModule = require('./app/techs/index');
require('angular-ui-router');
var routesConfig = require('./routes');

var main = require('./app/main');
var header = require('./app/header');
var footer = require('./app/footer');

require('./index.scss');
require('font-awesome');

angular
  .module('app', [techsModule, 'ui.router'])
  .config(routesConfig)
  .component('app', main)
  .component('fountainHeader', header)
  .component('fountainFooter', footer);
```

Comment: Did you take a look at https://gist.github.com/Turbo87/e8e941e68308d3b40ef6 or https://github.com/gowravshekar/font-awesome-webpack ? Here's another example of getting font awesome to work with webpack http://www.mattzabriskie.com/blog/font-awesome-webpack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that CommonJs does not know how to load `font-awesome`. If you take a look at the [Font Awesome package.json](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/package.json) it does not have `main` property which is used to find a file to load. Instead there is a property `style`. If you look at [the official package.json explanation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) you would not be able to find `style` property anywhere. You can find similar questions [in StackOverflow about style property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037150/style-field-in-package-json)

I believe your best bet is to require a specific file from the `node_module` directory. Taking an assumption that `src/` folder located in your root app folder

```
require('../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css');
// or
require('../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css');
```