# Is it possible to specify compiled and uncompiled main files in package.json

Tags: npm, package

It's possible to specify a "style" property in package.json that [exposes a packages CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037150/style-field-in-package-json).

Is there any way to specify a compiled and uncompiled main file?

For example, let's assume I've created a widget, that comes with it's own CSS, and I've built my widget with CSS Modules and compiled it with webpack. The compiled version it going to contain a lot of bloat. It'll have the webpack runtime, the embedded CSS, and any other dependencies I've included.

Is there a way to specify a file that a tool like webpack or rollup 'etc' would use when compiling the imports, so the my widget is compiled using the consumers build process?

Comment: Would this be for CSS or JS?

Comment: JS, which may in turn import it's own dependencies such as CSS, Json, raw text etc.

Comment: Generally speaking, I don't think you can. Exposing uncompiled files doesn't work too well, since the end-user must have a webpack config that can handle importing CSS, JSON, raw text, etc. Also, if the webpack config changes in a non-major release, that can introduce breaking changes. Do remember that (supposing your uncompiled main entry point is `src/index.js`) you can do `require('my-module/src')` if you really know what you're doing.