# What is the role of package.json fields "sass" and "style"?

Tags: npm, bootstrap-4

There is bootstrap 4 package.json
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/package.json

There are several interesting fields `style` and `sass` (unknown for me)

```
{
  //...
  "style": "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
  "sass": "scss/bootstrap.scss",
  "main": "dist/js/bootstrap",
  //...
}
```

Since they precede the highly important `main` field I start thinking that they are also very important. Can you advice on their role? I'm sure that `node-sass` works without them so which tool is a target?

Comment: Style: https://jaketrent.com/post/package-json-style-attribute/

Comment: Thank you. I was concentraded on sass and miss that there is style field description. Anyway without you it would very complex to find.

Comment: Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037150/style-field-in-package-json) regarding the `style` field.